# Let R be the relation on Z, defined as follows: ∀m, n∈Z, mRn⇐⇒2|(m−n) Determine whether the relation is reflextive, symmetric, and/or transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let R be the relation on Z, defined as follows:
∀m,n∈Z, mRn⇐⇒2|(m−n)

Determine whether the relation is reflextive, symmetric, and/or transitive

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

$2/m-n$  so $m-n=2k$ that mean $m=n[2]$

And we know $m=n[2]$$\Leftrightarrow $$n=m[2]$ so this relation is symmetry

and also we know  $m=m[2]$ so it's reflexive

And we know if $m=n[2] $ and $n=j[2]$ that's implies $ m=j[2]$ So it's transitive

And after this(transitivity, reflexivity, symmetry) we can say this relation is  an equivalence relation